# Spring how to trigger NoHandlerFoundException before any filter on unknown endpoints

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404, servlet-filters

I'm having an issue with Spring : NoHandlerFoundException is thrown really late after each of my filters. Therefore, the request gets stopped by my authentication filter before it is even marked as a Not Found. Anyone has an idea for how to make Spring trigger NoHandlerFoundException before any other filter or execution process in case of an unknown endpoint?